# firestore cloud messaging iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I cannot get a new record entry into my **firestore** document db to generate an alert to users.

1. IOS app fetches and updates firestore data with no issues
2. If I manually send a message from firebase my app gets the message no issues
3. I can deploy my cloud function to firebase with no errors

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions')
let admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

let db = admin.firestore()

  exports.announceAlert = functions.database
    .ref('/alerts/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        let alert = snapshot.val()
        sendNotification(alert)
    })

function sendNotification(alert) {

    let title = alert.Incident_Number
    let summary = alert.Flash_Summary
    let status = alert.Incident_Status  


    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Critical Incident: ' + title, 
            body: 'Summary: ' + summary,
            sound: 'default' 

        }
    }

    console.log(payload)

    let topic = "Alerts"
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked. Please keep in mind that the user of your iOS app has to subscribe to the topic and you do that through the app. The code below is just a function telling firebase to send a notification to subscribed users when a new document is created in a certain repository.

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions')
let admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

let db = admin.firestore()
  exports.announceMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('/myData/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        let message = snapshot.data()
        sendNotification(message)
    })

function sendNotification(message) {

    let title = message.column1  
    let notification = message.column2

    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Some title: ' + title, 
            body: 'Some header: ' + notification

        },


    }

console.log(payload)
let topic = "yourTopic"
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)

}
```